# How can I see sent/received data by netcat?

Tags: linux, netcat

I follow this post to [check speed with netcat](http://deice.daug.net/netcat_speed.html) , but in his blog when he do `ctrl-c` ,he get data on sent received bytes.

In the post he ran :

```
time yes|nc -v -v -n 192.168.0.8 2222 >/dev/null
than after ctrl-c het get:
sent 87478272, rcvd 0
real 0m9.993s
user 0m2.075s
sys 0m0.939s
```

When I do `ctrl-c` , I don't get this data.

How can I get sent/received data by netcat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually [two implementations of netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Variants), the [original implementation by *Hobbit*](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/) (called `netcat-traditional` in Debian/Ubuntu) and the [OpenBSD implementation](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/) (called `netcat-openbsd` in Debian/Ubuntu). In Debian/Ubuntu the binaries are called `nc.traditional` and `nc.openbsd` respectively (and `nc` is a link to one of those via the alternatives system).

The blog post you reference is using `nc.traditional` which does show the sent/received bytes when exiting. You are probably using `nc.openbsd` which doesn't. Install the traditional implementation and call it explicitly.

```
% time yes | nc.traditional -vvn 127.0.0.1 10000 > /dev/null
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 10000 (webmin) open
^C sent 99422208, rcvd 0
yes  1,06s user 0,09s system 38% cpu 3,003 total
```

Alternately, if you prefer to use the `nc.openbsd` you can pipe the output of netcat on the server side to `wc -c` and inspect the output like so:

```
% nc -l -n -p 10000 | wc --bytes
99422208
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Pipe Viewer (pv) utility](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to watch the visual progress of a stream. It can be modified to display the units of choice and is available on most distributions.

Example:

```
cat largefile | pv | netcat 192.168.10.1000 1234
```

Comment: I want to get it from netcat like in the posted blog ?

Comment: Please show your command string.

Comment: add this to the question, thank you. You can see it in the blog link.

Comment: `time yes|nc -v -v -n 192.168.0.8 2222 | pv | >/dev/null`

Comment: i copy paste the command that you wrote (in the comment), in the server side the pv display rate, but on the client side the pv display rate of 0

Comment: Experiment with it. I was just recommending the tool. You'll have to tailor it to your specific needs.

Comment: The command should be like this - time yes| pv | nc -v -v -n 192.168.0.8 2222  >/dev/null